# Two protons moving apart

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, electrostatics

I am an engineering student and I like to come up with random dynamics problems to test myself. Currently in first semester of Dynamics and just took Diff Eq last semester. I was looking for some insight into the nature of a certain type of problem.

My problem: Two protons located on x-axis at positions -d and +d. Solve for position as function of time (symbolically) once released from rest. Ignore all magnetic effects and the net force acting on each particle is only Coulomb's Law.

The simpler version: One of the particles is held stationary and the other one is allowed to move.

For the simpler version (one proton at origin not moving, other proton at distance d and repelled along x-axis), I got to where I needed to solve:

x'' = (k*q^2/m)*x^-2

What I want to understand better is did I end up at a 2nd Order Nonlinear ODE (PDE?) and how is this solved? I figured this is the simplest version of many dynamic problems that involve inverse-square forces. I just looked back at my phys 2 textbook and realized there was probably a reason they never had the particle's moving. I have had a hard time finding anything describing this problem that doesn't just describe electromagnetic effects, where I mainly just want to use this problem as a way to better understand solving for position using inverse-square forces.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of problem that energy was invented for.

Answer (score 2):

Multiply both sides of the equation by $x’$. This makes both sides be total time derivatives. (I’ll let you figure out of what.) This then gives you an equation with only first time derivatives, which you can solve by separating variables and integrating both sides.

You can get the simpler equation in the first place by starting from the conservation of energy instead of starting from Newton's Second Law. In physics, it is *almost always* better to start from energy conservation if possible.

By the way, this is just like radial infall under Newtonian gravity, except repulsive instead of attractive. (“Outfall”?)

The attractive variant (either electrostatic or gravitational) has been asked many times on this site, so if you get stuck you can try searching for those.

Answer (score 0):

You have time, a function of time, and the second derivative of that function. So yes, it's a second order ODE. It's not a PDE because the function is a function of only one variable.  As to how to solve it, suppose that $x$ is proportional to $x=t^n$. Then $x''$ is proportional to $t^{n-2}$. And $x^{-2}$ is proportional to $t^{-2n}$. So something proportional to $t^{n-2}$ is equal to something proportional to $t^{-2n}$. Thus, $n-2=-2n$. This should get you to one solution. But second order equation have two independent solutions. To get the other, you can use [reduction of order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_of_order).